# How to manage file sent to my grails

Tags: grails

I'm having trouble how to manage the audio file sent by cordova to my grails server to transform into bytes, because I don't know how to recover the audio sent to my 'audioDeal' method, I've tried using `params.fileName`, `params.options` ... :
cordova

```
ft.upload(currentPath, "http://blablabla:8080/audio/audioDeal", function (result) {
},
    function (error) {
    console.log('Error uploading file ' + currentPath + ': ' + error.code);
},
{ fileName: currentName });
```

My File domain have byte[] audioFile. My 'data' would be my object, should contain, name, size etc.

```
def audioDeal() {
    if (params.data) {
    def data = params.data
    def audio = new Test(audioFile: data.getBytes(), audio_name: data.name, id: data.id);
    audio.save(flush: true);
    println('ok')
    } else println('not ok')
}
```

My url mapping:

```
"/audio/" {
    controller = "testRest"
    action = [POST: "audioDeal", GET: "audioDeal", PUT: "audioDeal"]
}
```

Doing this, is the right way to storage the file in byte array? Any comments, advices, explanation about it, would be nice
...

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles tells you how to do it.

Comment: @TomW I'm not using Grails support `MultipartHttpServletRequest` through `.gsp`.

Comment: MultipartHttpServletRequest should work even without a .gsp - cordova should be sending though that kind of request, so the controller code in the docs should work I think (e.g. using request.getFile('file') - I think 'file' is the default key sent by Cordova).

Comment: It didn't worked, gives me an error `No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use method **data.transferTo(new File('file'))** or read bytes from **data.inputStream**

Comment: Actually @TomW was correct using getFiles('file'). Thanks anyway!